# Netscalar redirect request to OpenShift route

Tags: api, openshift, netscaler

Currently we have a C# web api running on 2 IIS servers, We are using Netscalar to load balance between IIS1 and IIS2 servers.

We have containerized our API and deployed it to OpenShift, as part of our testing initially we would like to point OpenShift as third node.

Means Netscalar should forward the request to OpenShift route also.

How can this be achieved in Netscalar.

My OpenShift route name is different so we tried specifying URL transformation rule to redirect IIS incoming request to OpenShift exposed route, but we are facing 503 service unavailable error.

What is the right way of configuring Netscalar to my API request are handled between IIS1, IIS2 and OpenShift ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think in most cases URL transformation is necessary. In a `Route` you can specify any `host` that you would like, so you can use your old DNS name. When a request with that HTTP `Host` header arrives at the OpenShift cluster (specifically at any Router Pod) it will be forwarded to your application.

```
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: my-route
...
spec:
  host: www.example.com
...
```

Your Netscaler load balancer needs to forward the traffic to the OpenShift Load Balancer (which is typically a separate IP), which in turn will forward it to the Router Pods.